# MDLabel not updating the value, from database Kivy+Python

Tags: python, kivy

Apparently my MDLabel won't update the value of passing from database. I don't know how to pass it.

Method had been try:

1. Using Object Property (not working )

Please help me!!
class YourRestaurant(Screen):

```
#nama_rest = StringProperty("")

def status_restaurant(self):
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='',
        port='3306',
        database=''
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    my_command = "SELECT username, idUser FROM User"
    mycursor.execute(my_command)
    fetchinfo = mycursor.fetchall()

    for data in fetchinfo:
        if data[0] == self.ids.kenal.text:  
            y = (data[1])  
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            my_command = "SELECT rest_name,address, idUser FROM Restaurant"
            mycursor.execute(my_command)
            fetchinfo = mycursor.fetchall()
            for i in fetchinfo:
                if i[2] == y: #owner_rest wujud
                    self.ids.nama_rest.text = (i[0])
                    #i want to update the nama_rest with the value of i[0]
                    # self.nama_rest carried the value from database, checked!
                    

    mydb.commit()
```

Here my .kv file

:
name: "YourRestaurant"

```
MDToolbar:
    md_bg_color: 1,1,1,1
    pos_hint: {"top": 1}
    left_action_items: [['chevron-left', lambda x: root.go_back()]]
    specific_text_color: [191/255,54/255,37/255,1] ##bf3625 merah bata

KenaliSaya:
    id: kenal

    MDLabel:
      id: nama_rest
      text: root.nama_rest
```

This is my error. And if any of you have explanation regarding this, so I can learn . Help me !!
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the label text with `self.ids.kenal.ids.nama_rest.text`

`kivy.properties.ObservableDict.getattr AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'getattr'` is usually thrown when an id cannot be accessed.  With the above you are explicitly pointing to the id.  In your code, Kivy is looking for a widget which is the child of the root widget, the screen.  However the label is instead a child of your KenaliSaya.

Hope this works.